# Instead of logging a user's coordinates (double) when he logs in, how can location delegate check the location when he is on the move?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

Currently the user location is logged each time he visits the home screen. It needs to also update when the user is on the move so that the location stays current.

Here I set the location upon login

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
     let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid         
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    latestLocation = ["latitude" : locValue.latitude, "longitude" : locValue.longitude]
    let lat = locValue.latitude
    let lon = locValue.longitude
    dict = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    print("dict", dict)


    if let locationDictionary = latestLocation {
        databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").setValue(locationDictionary)

    }


}
```

Now I just nee it to always setValue when user moves materially.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` method and don't for get to call `startUpdatingLocation`

Comment: Will do. I just got a weir message on iPhone today that the app which I am testing on there accessed location 38 times in 3 days. Is there anything in my code that already updates the location? I thought there wasn't

Comment: Check if you are calling `startUpdatingLocation` function anywhere.